# Embedding part of API code in PowerBI Dashboard

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-api

I'm setting up some Dashboards in PowerBI based on data imported via an API.

All the dashboards contain the same visuals, just the back-end data is specific to each client.

The API call is the same, apart from the end part of the key, which is specific to the client.

To save having 20 dashboards and changing the API key in all locations each time, can I have a hidden field on the Dashboard containing the code and reference that cell/text box in the API call code?